# How to convert a specified colour to transparent for a series of PNGs with ImageMagick?

Tags: transparency, png, batch-processing, imagemagick

I've installed ImageMagick on Windows 7 64-bit and I'm wondering how I can convert a series of PNGs to transparent PNGs in a timely manner (I have 180 PNGs to convert, so yeah I can't exactly do them each individually if I ever want to have spare time again).

How can I quickly edit the transparency of a colour for a batch of PNGs using ImageMagick?

Comment: this like may help http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/

Answer (score 1):

If the color of the original background is fixed (e.g. white), you can simply use [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) for all your images (see also [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=10665)):

```
convert input_image.png -transparent white output_image.png
```

If you don't want to use a batch file, you can use [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php), being aware that mogrify overwrite the original file.

This question is very frequent in StackExchange: for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155377/set-transparent-background-using-imagemagick-and-commandline-prompt) or [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389721/how-do-i-set-a-colour-to-be-transparent-in-a-gif-using-imagemagick).